# RxSwift Binding to an Enum

Tags: rx-swift

I have the following ViewModel which I want to bind to the UITextField and UISegmentedControl. I was able to successfully bind to the UITextField but UISegmentedControl binding is not working since my recommend data type is an enum.

```
enum Recommend: Int  {
    case yes = 0
    case no = 1
}

struct FeedbackViewModel {

    var name = Variable<String>("")
    var recommend = Variable<Recommend>(.yes) 

}
```

In my view controller I have the following bindings:

private func configureBindings() {

```
self.nameTextField.rx.text
        .orEmpty
        .bind(to: self.feedbackViewModel.name)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

self.recommendSegmentedControl.rx.value
    .bind(to: self.feedbackViewModel.recommend.value.rawValue)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

}

For the recommendSegmentedControl bind I get the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'bind' with an argument list of type '(to: Int)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first create a `Recommend` value.

```
self.recommendSegmentedControl.rx.value
    .map(Recommend.init(rawValue:))
    .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
    .bind(to: self.feedbackViewModel.recommend)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

You could also do it this way if you are feel like taking a small risk:

```
self.recommendSegmentedControl.rx.value
    .map { Recommend.init(rawValue: $0)! }
    .bind(to: self.feedbackViewModel.recommend)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!